# Segmentation fault: Pointer to an array of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have an array of String (`char **`) which is initialised as `NULL`. After passing its address when I try to access its elements it gives segmentation fault.

```
//following code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void parse(char ***test, char *str)
{
    int i;
    *test = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        *test[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
        strcpy(*test[i], str);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *str = "Hello world";
    char **test = NULL;
    parse(&test, str);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        printf("%s\n", test[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

On using debugger inside the function parse all elements have correct values and properly initialised and allocated but from main function only 0 indexed row gives the correct value rest are segment fault.

Comment: There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` and friends, nor is recommended in any way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*test[0]` should be `(*test)[i]`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence says that `[]` has higher priority than `*`, which is not what you want.

You should also not overwrite the index 0.

`sizeof(char)` is always 1 and so you can leave it away. You should also not cast the return value of `malloc` and test for success.

Comment: This never struck me!! Amazing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is

```
*test[0] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
```

you're always allocating memory to the index `0`.

Also, following the [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), you need to dereference `test` first, then apply the idexing on that, so, you basically need to re-write your code like

```
(*test)[0]  = malloc( strlen(str) + 1);
```

Please note:

1. [See why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to produce `1`. Multiplying by it is redundant.

Comment: that was a typo!! I have edited that!! Problem still persists!